# WineHQ/ application cannot locate it's DLL

Tags: 14.04, wine, winetricks

I am running Ubuntu 14.04 w/ wine1.6. also tried with wine1.7 I am trying to run SimCity 2013 which I know works perfectly fine with any Windows machine. When I run the exe it returns:

> "Error Code: [4000] SimCity could not find the EA WebKit DLL. SimCity will now exit."

The dll is named "eawebkit.dll"

I tried using winetricks and add the dll and select every option available to no avail.

The file is in the correct folder in order to run just as another machine running Win 7 does. My thoughts are, there is some configuration file possibly needing altered. I think the program is looking outside the .wine/drive_c parameters.

Any thoughts? Tricks? Bag of bones??

Here is the output:

```
fixme:hnetcfg:fw_profile_get_ExceptionsNotAllowed 0x146e18, 0x32fd2c
fixme:hnetcfg:fw_app_get_Enabled 0x146e30, 0x32fd34
fixme:hnetcfg:fw_app_put_ProcessImageFileName 0x146e78, L"C:\Games\SimCity 2013 Offline\SimCity\SimCity.exe"
fixme:hnetcfg:fw_app_put_Name 0x146e78, L"SimCity"
fixme:hnetcfg:fw_apps_Add 0x146e30, 0x146e78
fixme:thread:SetThreadIdealProcessor (0xb4): stub
fixme:thread:SetThreadIdealProcessor (0xbc): stub
fixme:system:SetProcessDPIAware stub!
fixme:xinput:XInputGetState (0 0x32f410)
fixme:ole:RemUnknown_QueryInterface No interface for iid {00000019-0000-0000-c000-000000000046}
fixme:win:EnumDisplayDevicesW ((null),0,0x32ee68,0x00000000), stub!
fixme:thread:SetThreadIdealProcessor (0x1d8): stub
err:ole:CoInitializeEx Attempt to change threading model of this apartment from apartment threaded to multi-threaded
fixme:winediag:AUDDRV_GetAudioEndpoint Winepulse is not officially supported by the wine project
fixme:winediag:AUDDRV_GetAudioEndpoint For sound related feedback and support, please visit http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1960599
fixme:d3d:resource_check_usage Unhandled usage flags 0x8.
fixme:d3d:resource_check_usage Unhandled usage flags 0x8.
fixme:d3d:resource_check_usage Unhandled usage flags 0x8.
fixme:d3d:resource_check_usage Unhandled usage flags 0x8.
fixme:d3d:resource_check_usage Unhandled usage flags 0x8.
fixme:d3d:resource_check_usage Unhandled usage flags 0x8.
fixme:d3d:resource_check_usage Unhandled usage flags 0x8.
fixme:d3d:resource_check_usage Unhandled usage flags 0x8.
fixme:d3d:resource_check_usage Unhandled usage flags 0x8.
fixme:d3d:resource_check_usage Unhandled usage flags 0x8.
fixme:d3d:resource_check_usage Unhandled usage flags 0x8.
fixme:d3d:resource_check_usage Unhandled usage flags 0x8.
fixme:d3d:resource_check_usage Unhandled usage flags 0x8.
fixme:d3d:resource_check_usage Unhandled usage flags 0x8.
fixme:d3d:resource_check_usage Unhandled usage flags 0x8.
fixme:d3d:resource_check_usage Unhandled usage flags 0x8.
fixme:d3d:resource_check_usage Unhandled usage flags 0x8.
fixme:d3d:resource_check_usage Unhandled usage flags 0x8.
fixme:d3d:resource_check_usage Unhandled usage flags 0x8.
fixme:d3d:resource_check_usage Unhandled usage flags 0x8.
fixme:d3d:resource_check_usage Unhandled usage flags 0x8.
fixme:d3d:resource_check_usage Unhandled usage flags 0x8.
fixme:d3d:resource_check_usage Unhandled usage flags 0x8.
fixme:d3d:resource_check_usage Unhandled usage flags 0x8.
fixme:d3d:resource_check_usage Unhandled usage flags 0x8.
fixme:d3d:resource_check_usage Unhandled usage flags 0x8.
fixme:d3d:resource_check_usage Unhandled usage flags 0x8.
fixme:d3d:resource_check_usage Unhandled usage flags 0x8.
fixme:d3d:resource_check_usage Unhandled usage flags 0x8.
fixme:d3d:resource_check_usage Unhandled usage flags 0x8.
fixme:d3d:resource_check_usage Unhandled usage flags 0x8.
fixme:d3d:resource_check_usage Unhandled usage flags 0x8.
fixme:d3d:resource_check_usage Unhandled usage flags 0x8.
fixme:d3d:resource_check_usage Unhandled usage flags 0x8.
fixme:d3d:resource_check_usage Unhandled usage flags 0x8.
fixme:d3d:resource_check_usage Unhandled usage flags 0x8.
fixme:d3d:resource_check_usage Unhandled usage flags 0x8.
fixme:d3d:resource_check_usage Unhandled usage flags 0x8.
fixme:d3d:debug_d3dformat Unrecognized 0x36314644 (as fourcc: DF16) WINED3DFORMAT!
fixme:d3d:wined3d_get_format Can't find format unrecognized (0x36314644) in the format lookup table
fixme:d3d:debug_d3dformat Unrecognized 0x34324644 (as fourcc: DF24) WINED3DFORMAT!
fixme:d3d:wined3d_get_format Can't find format unrecognized (0x34324644) in the format lookup table
```

Comment: "bag of bones" ... https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=27821

Comment: wasn’t much info on that link w/ examples of error messages. Just a general solution with no background information...

Comment: The only suggestion I've got is to investigate whether the latest wine 1.7 improves matters.  If you try this remember to submit a test result on winehq - if it works ... you can add this as an answer yourself.  good luck.

Comment: I tried 1.6, 1.7 & 1.7beta. No luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this on my own after 5 days of troubleshooting and tinkering around:

Installed via PlayLinux and choose wine1.5.20 version for the application. Now it runs with out the error!!

and able to run updates!! Whoohooo!

[image]